# Posts - display all posts except a post by an ID

Tags: posts, query-posts

I want to be able to display all posts except a the most recent post which I am doing as follows:-

```
$last = wp_get_recent_posts( '1');
$last_id = $last['0']['ID'];

echo $last_id; //1477

$args = array('posts_per_page' => 5,
              'post__not_in'   => array($last_id),
);

$recent_posts = get_posts('numberposts=10&exclude='. $post_id .'"');

if($recent_posts) { ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ) { ?>
        <li>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($recent->ID); ?>"><?php echo $recent->post_title; ?></a>
        </li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

`$last_id` contains the correct value for the most recent post, but the code is still displaying the ten most recent posts without excluding any.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of issues here

- IIRC, `exclude` should be an array of ID's as `exclude` get passed to `WP_Query` as `post_not_in`
- You are defining arguments which you don't use. You could have simply passed that to `get_posts`. Rememeber, all parameters in `WP_Query` is available as is to `get_posts` as `get_posts` uses `WP_Query`
- You can simply use `'offset' => 1,` to skip the most recent post. You are running total unnecesarry queries here which slows your page down

You can try the following

```
$args = [
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'offset' => 1
];
$recent_posts = get_posts( $args );
```